# Is $x_1^{\alpha_1} + \dotsb + x_n^{\alpha_n}\geq x_1^{h/n}\dotsb x_n^{h/n}$ an example of power means?

Tags: calculus, limits, arithmetic, average

I learned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531831/why-is-the-0th-power-mean-defined-to-be-the-geometric-mean) that there is a relation between weighted means of the form $x_1^{\lambda_1}\dotsb x_n^{\lambda_n}$ and $(\lambda_1 x_1^r + \dotsb + \lambda_nx_n^r)^{1/r}$, namely that the former is the limit of the latter as $r\to 0$ (so the geometric mean is the $0$th power mean).

I learned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530190/show-that-int-1-infty-dotsb-int-1-infty-fracdx-1-dotsb-dx-nx-1-a) that there is an inequality $x_1^{\alpha_1} + \dotsb + x_n^{\alpha_n}\geq x_1^{h/n}\dotsb x_n^{h/n}$, where $h = h(\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_n)$ is the harmonic mean of the $\alpha_i$, where $x_i>0$ and $\alpha_i >0$.

My question is: are the two related? I was looking for a way to generalize the second result above, and I wondered if it was naturally related to generalized power means. Any ideas, folks?

Comment: It might be noticed that the inequality in your second  paragraph can be replaced by a more precise one, $\frac{h}{n}(\frac{x_1^{\alpha_1}}{\alpha_1} + \dotsb + \frac{x_n^{\alpha_n}}{\alpha_n})\geq x_1^{h/n}\dotsb x_n^{h/n}$, which is equivalent to the inequality between weighted means.

Comment: @Landscape I think I'm missing how that is equivalent to the inequality between weighted means...on the left side, the terms have different exponents, whereas above all the terms have exponent $r$.

Comment: Compare $\lambda_1y_1+\cdots+\lambda_ny_n\ge \left(y_1^{\lambda_1}\cdots y_n^{\lambda_n}\right)^r$ with the inequality in my last comment. Then we can find the following correspondence: $\frac{h}{n\alpha_i}\leftrightarrow \lambda_i$ and $x_i^{\alpha_i}\leftrightarrow y_i$.